# File include confusion and errors

Tags: php, require

I have the following directory structure.

```
public_html
    |----------app1
    |            |---------config.php
    |            |---------index.php 
    |
    |----------app2
                 |---------import.php
```

app1/config.php

```
define('ABC', 'hello');
```

app1/index.php

```
require_once 'config.php';
echo ABC;
```

Calling `app1/index.php` prints:

> Hello

app2/import.php

```
require_once('../app1/index.php');
```

Calling `app2/import.php` prints:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ABC - assumed 'ABC' in /abs/path/public_html/app1/index.php on line 10 (line echo ABC)
>
> ABC

Why does this happen?

How would one include in order to make it work properly?

Comment: Use `__DIR__` whenever dealing with paths; e.g: `require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php'`

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the problem?

Comment: Sure thing @Lemures - it's a magic constant defined in PHP which represents the directory of the current file being executed. This makes it easy to dynamically include/require other scripts relative to your current file; e.g: `__DIR__ '/fileinsamedirectory.php'` or `__DIR__ . '/../fileinparentdirectory.php'`. You'll find it's used a lot in modern PHP when resolving file includes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [documentation about `include` and `require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Relative paths are always resolved relatively to the first called script.

So, when you call `app1/index.php`, `require_once('config.php')` loads `app1/index.php`, but when you call `app2/import.php`, `require_once('config.php')`*tries* to load **`app2/config.php`** which does not exist.

*Advice 1*: raise you [error reporting level](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) when you are coding, you will get more clues about what's wrong. In this case, `include` through at least a notice.

*Advice 2*: avoid `include` if you have no good reason, use `require_once` which will make an fatal error when unable to load the file.

Comment: Ok. Then why when providing absolute path inside the include it does not work?

Comment: My bad, using absolute paths everywhere, works fine.

Comment: Now, tell me, which is better?
Definin in config.php an `APP_ABS_PATH` and use it in all requires, or use `__DIR__` everywhere?

Comment: `__DIR__` is much more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
```

instead of `require_once 'config.php';`

Refrence : [PHP file paths and magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you run script `php app2/import.php` from folder `public_html` not from `public_html/app2`.

 If you do this:

```
cd app2 && php import.php
```

All will work!

Your example with `require_once 'config.php';` in `app1/index.php` works because files `index.php` and `config.php` placed in same directory.

But `app2/import.php` placed in another directory from `app1/config.php` hence you can't use this approach in this case.

With purpose avoid this mess with relative paths you have to use constant `__DIR__` in your paths in `import.php`, like this :

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../app1/index.php');
```

and now you can run this script from `public_html` directory.

Comment: Now, tell me, which is better? Definin in config.php an `APP_ABS_PATH` and use it in all requires, or use `__DIR__` everywhere?

Comment: @Lemures The best approach is define const `APP_ABS_PATH ` and use it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking, I would have to define absolute path for each app in each config and in order to use the constant, I'd have to include the configs without using the constant, hence I guess it's better to use `__DIR__`, as I don't see any downside of it...

Comment: @Lemures In general you have to have 1 main config for application and use this config everywhere in code... It's better to avoid shared configs between applications...

Comment: I agree, but in order to include that config correctly, I'd have to use DIR, and since I define all my constants inside config, then defining the ABS PATH would be kinda useless (except the case when dealing with files)